# Page number for chapter page centred

Tags: formatting

I am searching for an answer to a page numbering issue. 
The document is;

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=6.125in:9.25in, twoside=true, pagesize=pdftex, BCOR=0.375in]{scrbook}
```

With

```
\areaset{4.625in}{7.625in} % in header.tex 1st brace {BCOR} not included as is included main file bookgrs.tex in \documentclass

\flushbottom % text length same at bottom of pages
\frontmatter % pagenumbering in lowercase roman located in header.tex

\mainmatter % pagenumbering in arabic located in initial.tex
```

The page numbers appear in the centre at the bottom of all the pages except the actual first page of each chapter where they locate at the right margin. I am using `fancyhdr` and `fancy` packages.

```
% Fancyhdr commands

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}

\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}

%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\cfoot{\thepage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Is there a way to have the chapter page number centred? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks, Geoff.

Comment: Added the \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
} and problem resolved. Page number on chapter pages in centre.

Answer (score 2):

Chapter pages use page style `plain`. So you have to define this page style accordingly:

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=6.125in:9.25in, twoside=true, pagesize, BCOR=0.375in]{scrbook}
\areaset[current]{4.625in}{7.625in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

You could also use package `scrlayer-scrpage` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle.

```
\documentclass[10pt, paper=6.125in:9.25in, twoside=true, pagesize, BCOR=0.375in]{scrbook}
\areaset[current]{4.625in}{7.625in}

\usepackage[automark,markcase=upper,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```